# Could anybody explain this code's output?

Tags: c

the answer is 90. But what is the logic for this?
in case i write this j=(4,5);
then answer is 5.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    void main()
    {
        int j;
        j=(4,5,90);
        printf("%d\n",j);
    }
```

Comment: Please read this: [Comma Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)

Comment: What did you expect it to be? Why did you write this code? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 8):

You are using the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator):

> In the C and C++ programming languages, the comma operator (represented by the token ,) is a binary operator that evaluates its first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second operand and returns this value (and type).

Note that this is not the same as the comma that separates function arguments.

```
a = 1, 2, 3;
     ^  ^
     |  |
  comma operators

a = foo(1, 2, 3);
         ^  ^
         |  |
      separators
```

For your code this means that all that happens is that the expressions `4`, `5` and `90` are evaluated one by one, and the result of this is the result of the last expression, i.e. `90`.

The parentheses are just parentheses, they don't affect the result in any way.

```
const int j = (4, 5, 90);
```

Is the same as:

```
const int j = 4, 5, 90;
```

Or, for that matter:

```
const int j = (4), (5), (90);
```

As is noted on the Wikipedia page I linked to, and should be obvious from the above, the comma operator is very rarely useful. It can be tricked into service for various obscure purposes (see [this page for examples](http://mindtribe.com/2011/07/forgotten-c-the-comma-operator/)) but doing obscure things is rarely a win.

Comment: The comma acts as a separator and not as an operator. Since it has lower precedence than assignment.

Comment: i could not understand clearly what explanation u gave "unwind". Could u please explain it in more simple manner?

Comment: @Juna I added more words, hopefully clearer now.

Comment: @unwind Doesn't the comma have lower precedence than assignment? thus without parenthesis `const int j = 4,5,90;` would be like `const int j = 4; 5,90;` resulting in an error :?

Comment: @a3f Did you read any of the above? The *comma operator* is being used, it is a binary operator which syntactically is just like any other, e.g. `+`. You wouldn't expect `const int j = 4 + 5 + 90;` to parse as if there was semi-colons in there, would you?

Comment: @unwind well + has higher precedence than assignment. I just tried `const int j=4,5,90;`' and indeed throws an error.

Comment: @unwind `int j = 4,5,90;` **is** a syntax error. On the other hand `j = 4, 5, 90;` would not be, and it would assign 4 to `j` (that is, it would be **different** from `j = (4, 5, 90);`).